# iphone app is 100+mb, does itunes take care of hosting?

Tags: iphone

I have developing an iphone app with lots of media files bundled. If I submit it to apple and apple accepts it, do I have to take care of the hosting? Or is that taken care of by apple?

Comment: Does it need to be 100+ MB?  Since I have a 16G iPhone, with photos and music, that's getting to be a significant fraction of my available space.

Answer (score 1):

Only Apple can host iPhone/iOS apps for stock devices (that aren't among the up to 100 logged in your developer portal).

There are limits.  Over 20MB may limit how some customers might be able to load your app.

Answer (score 0):

When you upload your app to iTunes Connect, Apple will take care of all of the file hosting needs, so in short, No, You personally do not need to host anything, it will be taken care of by Apple.

Apple will also put together the app description page based on the information you provide when you set up your app in iTunes Connect, including update information, screenshots and the large icon (which you will need to provide).

Answer (score 0):

If you have the media files bundled with your app, Apple will take care of them. Have a look at most games — a 1GB game is the norm. You, however, should weigh the advantages and disadvantages of having everything inside the app bundle vs. just the base app and the ability to download them on demand. Note the 20MB limit on downloading app using a data connection — many developers say that it hinders their sales.